# Issues using cURL through PHP for HTTP POST with $_FILES

Tags: php, curl

Essentially, what I have to do is take a HTTP Post, and save the file on a first server, and then forward the post to a second server which saves the file again and then generates an email with the file as an attachment. Presently, I have it working where I send the post to the second server, and it creates the email and sends it out, so that's not an issue.

However, when I tried adding the first server in there, I cannot get it to send at all, or print out a meaningful result. Here is the code for the send/receive script:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/www/myfirstsite.com/3d/';
$uploadname = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $uploadname;


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "OK\n";
} else {
    echo "ERROR\n";
}
echo "<br>";

$url = 'http://mysecondsite.com:12345/receive_scan.php';
//I use port 12345 because most of the important ports are being used already. 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_FILES);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
$result='Result: '.curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;
echo curlerrno($ch);
echo curlerror($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Presently, when I send a HTTP post request, it prints out this:

```
OK
Result:
```

The code that I use to send the HTTP post request is this:

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://myfirstsite.com/receive_scan.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The code on the second server that receives, which works with this code above if I just change the site, is this:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './scans/';
$uploadname = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . uploadname;

echo "File Received\n";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK\n";
} else {
    echo "ERROR\n";
}
shell_exec("bash sendmail.bash ".$uploadfile." ".$uploadname);
?>
```

The sendmail.bash is just a script that usings msmtp to send an email to my email.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of $_FILES and curl post are different -I've hit this problem about 3 years ago, took me about 3 days to resolve:

```
function arraysToBrackets($array, $prefix, $level=0){

    $resarr = array();
    foreach ($array as $field => $data){
        if (is_array($data)){
            $resarr = array_merge($resarr, arraysToBrackets($data,
                    ($prefix?$prefix.'['.$field.']':$field),$level+1));
        }else{
            if ($level > 0){
                $resarr[$prefix.'['.$field.']'] = $data;
            }else{
                $resarr[$prefix.$field] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
    return $resarr;
}

$postThrough = arraysToBrackets($_POST);

if ($_FILES){

    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $details){
        if (is_array($details['name'])){
            foreach ($_FILES[$file]['name'] as $file2 => $details2){
                if ($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'][$file2]){
                    $postThrough[$file.'['.$file2.']'] = '@'.$_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'][$file2];
                }
            }
        }else{
            if ($details['tmp_file']){
                 $postThrough[$file] = '@'.$details['tmp_file'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```